# Mandar información de INPUT de html a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una aplicación para imprimir etiquetas, utilizo una `dll` que aún no termino de entender, pero quiero hacer esto:
Cuento con 3 input type en HTML en el cual agrego información para la creación de una etiqueta, lo que quiero es que esa información se pase en línea hacia un `textarea`

```html
<form>
  NUMERO DE SERIE:
  <input type="text" name="numeroserie"><br> REFERENCIA:
  <input type="text" name="referencia"><br> PESO (KG):
  <input type="number" name="peso"><br>

</form>
<textarea id="textToEncode" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

La `dll` o función que tengo cargada toma la información del `textarea` y la convierte en un código de barras, entonces como aun no entiendo cómo funciona, quiero pasar la información de los `textbox` hacia el `textarea`, como se puede ver en la imagen de abajo, al darle clic al botón Insertar.. me mande la información hacia el textarea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Lo que le falta al codigo es asignar los identificadores a los elementos del formulario, he agregado una respuesta en la que te explico una solucion que puede servirte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Primero

Si vas a utilizar **Javascript** **sin frameworks**, podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
function copiarDatos(){

  var numeroSerie = document.getElementById("numeroserie").value;
  var referencia = document.getElementById("referencia").value;
  var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;

  var texto = numeroSerie + "\t\t" + referencia + "\t\t" + peso;

  document.getElementById("textToEncode").innerHTML = texto;

}
```

```html
<form>
  NUMERO DE SERIE:
  <input type="text" id="numeroserie" name="numeroserie"><br> REFERENCIA:
  <input type="text" id="referencia" name="referencia"><br> PESO (KG):
  <input type="number" id="peso" name="peso"><br>
  <button type="button" id="boton" onClick="copiarDatos()">Insertar Información del Producto</button>

</form>
<textarea id="textToEncode" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

### Que hemos hecho aqui?

Lo primero que hemos hecho, es **asignar un identificador a los elementos del formulario**:

```
 <input type="text" id="numeroserie" name="numeroserie"><br> REFERENCIA:
 <input type="text" id="referencia" name="referencia"><br> PESO (KG):
 <input type="number" id="peso" name="peso"><br>
```

### Nos falta una funcion

Por lo tanto, hemos creado esta funcion, la cual se encargara de copiar los datos del formulario al `textarea`:

```
function copiarDatos(){

  var numeroSerie = document.getElementById("numeroserie").value;
  var referencia = document.getElementById("referencia").value;
  var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;

  var texto = numeroSerie + "\t\t" + referencia + "\t\t" + peso;

  document.getElementById("textToEncode").innerHTML = texto;

}
```

En esta funcion **obtenemos los valores respectivos del formulario, referenciando a cada elemento usando su identificador**. Posteriormente, los concatenamos todos usando el caracter `\t`, para que quede **tabulado** entre cada texto y guardamos todo esto en la variable `texto`.

### Por cierto

Debemos agregar esta funcion al boton, esto se haria asi:

```
<button type="button" id="boton" onClick="copiarDatos()">Insertar Información del Producto</button>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda, me sirvio de mucho, ya puedo realizar el proceso de la aplicación, ahora tengo que buscar la manera de meter espacios, por ejemplo para el numero de serie necesito que sean 16 caracteres si o si, ya sean 5 caracteres + 11 espacios, o 10 caracteres + 6 espacios siempre al final, sabrías como contar los caracteres y poner los espacios? Saludos!

Comment: @EduardoVelazquez No soy un experto, pero claro que te puedo ayudar! Solo debes [formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) y cualquier miembro de la comunidad podra ayudarte

Comment: Especifica bien lo que requieres en tu nueva pregunta, y asi podremos ayudarte :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con Jquery:
*Agrega los id a los textbox para que los puedas ubicar*

```
  NUMERO DE SERIE:
  <input type="text" name="numeroserie" id="numeroserie"><br>
  REFERENCIA:
  <input type="text" name="referencia" id="referencia"><br>
  PESO (KG):
  <input type="number" name="peso" id="peso"><br>

  <button id="miboton" onClick="pasardatos()">Insertar Información del Producto</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function pasardatos(){
var numeroserie = $("#numeroserie").val();
var referencia = $("#referencia").val();
var peso = $("#peso").val();

var datos = numeroserie+" "+referencia+" "+peso;

$("#textToEncode").val(datos); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando puro javascript necesitas identificar tu input con un id cambialo por lo siguiente

```
<input type="text" name="numeroserie" id="numeroserie">
```

Y para obtener sus valores utiliza lo siguiente

```
    document.getElementById("numeroserie").value();
```